# System of differential equations in RC

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics

[image]

I am struggling with **c) part** these differential equations, I am not sure i obtained it correctly or not, but i solved in matlab also, and i dont think it is correct answer.

My work:
$$-50q_1'-100000q_1+100(I-q_1')=0$$
$$-50q_2'-100000q_2+150(I-q_2')=0$$
$$-50q_1'-100000q_1-50q_2'-100000q_2+75=0$$

**Can you check my equations also?** Here $I$ is the function of time $t$
[image]

> If R1 and R3 are in parallel   and R2 and R3 in parallel always for any time t, then this question is a piece of cake for me. Can u confirm are they in parallel ? ?
>
> **I solved it using laplace and both MATLAB now, Thanks if anyone else has tried**

Comment: I checked my answers with LTspice, and mine are right.

Comment: Okay...so you mean first of all I divide by s and then take inverse Laplace transform??

Comment: yes indeed!!!!!!!!

Comment: okay i will try at home and let u know :D

Comment: Nice, I am curious if you now get it. If not, I am willing to help you further.

Comment: no no ,.,,,, u didnt see the question edit later.... I already solved the question using 3 different methods....!! But i will check your method is correct or not ... using the inverse laplce later.... that is what i said @Jan

Comment: I know my method is correct, but feel free to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{i}_\text{i}=\text{i}_1+\text{i}_3\\
\\
\text{i}_1=\text{i}_2+\text{i}_5\\
\\
\text{i}_4=\text{i}_3+\text{i}_5\\
\\
\text{i}_\text{i}=\text{i}_2+\text{i}_4
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{i}_1=\frac{\text{v}_\text{i}-\text{v}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{i}_2=\frac{\text{v}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{i}_3=\frac{\text{v}_\text{i}-\text{v}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{i}_3=\left(\text{v}_2-\text{v}_3\right)\text{sC}_1\\
\\
\text{i}_4=\frac{\text{v}_3-\text{v}_4}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{i}_4=\text{v}_4\text{sC}_2
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Here I used small letters to denote the s-domain (using the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)). And notice that $\text{v}_1=\text{v}_3$.

> Using $\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{s}\cdot\text{q}\left(\text{s}\right)$ it is possible to solve your problem. Using my equations you can solve for all voltages and currents. To do this fast you can use Mathematica for example.

---

Using this Mathematica code:

```
In[1]:=Vi = 75/s;
R1 = 100;
R2 = 150;
R3 = 50;
R4 = 50;
C1 = 10*10^(-6);
C2 = 10*10^(-6); FullSimplify[
 Solve[{V1 == V3, Ii == I1 + I3, I1 == I2 + I5, I4 == I3 + I5, 
   Ii == I2 + I4, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, I3 == (Vi - V2)/R3,
    I3 == (V2 - V3)*s*C1, I4 == (V3 - V4)/R4, I4 == V4*s*C2}, {Ii, I1,
    I2, I3, I4, I5, V1, V2, V3, V4}]]
```

I found:

```
Out[1]={{Ii -> (6 (500 + s) (2000 + 3 s))/(s (2000 + s) (10000 + 17 s)), 
  I1 -> (6 (500 + s))/(s (10000 + 17 s)), 
  I2 -> (6000 + 9 s)/(20000 s + 34 s^2), 
  I3 -> (12 (500 + s))/((2000 + s) (10000 + 17 s)), 
  I4 -> 3/4 (1/(2000 + s) + 1/(10000 + 17 s)), I5 -> 3/(20000 + 34 s),
   V1 -> 45 (1/s - 2/(10000 + 17 s)), 
  V2 -> 75/2 (2/s - 1/(2000 + s) + 1/(10000 + 17 s)), 
  V3 -> 45 (1/s - 2/(10000 + 17 s)), 
  V4 -> (450000 (2000 + 3 s))/(s (2000 + s) (10000 + 17 s))}}
```

To find $\text{q}\left(\text{s}\right)$, you can use:

$$\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{s}\cdot\text{q}\left(\text{s}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{q}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{s}}\tag3$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution , I don't know who have that thumbs down let me check your solution and after that I will vote up , I need charge I guess you didnt do the charge

Comment: @learningstudent true I see my mistake I will fix it as as soon as possible.

Comment: @learningstudent Look at my edit. Now it is correct.

Comment: @learningstudent I am now sure that my answer is correct.  And as I write in my answer, you can calculate q using: q = i / s.

Comment: @learningstudent btw I have a masters degree in electrical engineering.

Comment: I checked your work and it is correct ! +1

Comment: @learningstudent Thanks, but I knew ;)